# Why is my IR signal not powering on my TV

Tags: pi, infrared, pigpio

I am currently working on a personal project with pigpio and piscope on raspberry PI 4.
I try to simulate my TV remote by sending IR signal through an IR LED setup connected on **GPIO 23** and GND pin (setup is a simple IR LED with a 200 ohm resistor)
I searched on LIRC database my TV remote config file and I did not find it, but I found another one (MKJ40653802-TV) which is said to be working also for my TV which is a **LG 50PS3000**:

https://www.remote-control-world.eu/lg-c-2_64/lg-mkj42519615-replacement-remote-control-p-4195

also config file :

```
begin remote

  name  MKJ40653802-TV
  bits           16
  flags SPACE_ENC|CONST_LENGTH
  eps            30
  aeps          100

  header       9061  4473
  one           591  1660
  zero          591   521
  ptrail        590
  pre_data_bits   16
  pre_data       0x20DF
  gap          108029
  toggle_bit_mask 0x0

      begin codes
          KEY_POWER                0x10EF                    #  Was: power
```

After reading LIRC documentation and explainations on how to contruct an IR signal, I managed to get my hands through a python script which create IR waveform to be fired through IR LED

https://github.com/bschwind/ir-slinger/blob/master/pyslinger.py

I simply changed the NEC protocol paramters to the values present in the config file.
Also my power on/off hex value is 0x20DF23DC (pre-data + command) that I convert to binary 32 bits :
00100000110111110010001111011100

my code below :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Python IR transmitter
# Requires pigpio library
# Supports NEC, RC-5 and raw IR.
# Danijel Tudek, Aug 2016

import subprocess
import ctypes
import time

# This is the struct required by pigpio library.
# We store the individual pulses and their duration here. (In an array of these structs.)
class Pulses_struct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("gpioOn", ctypes.c_uint32),
                ("gpioOff", ctypes.c_uint32),
                ("usDelay", ctypes.c_uint32)]

# Since both NEC and RC-5 protocols use the same method for generating waveform,
# it can be put in a separate class and called from both protocol's classes.
class Wave_generator():
    def __init__(self,protocol):
        self.protocol = protocol
        MAX_PULSES = 12000 # from pigpio.h
        Pulses_array = Pulses_struct * MAX_PULSES
        self.pulses = Pulses_array()
        self.pulse_count = 0

    def add_pulse(self, gpioOn, gpioOff, usDelay):
        self.pulses[self.pulse_count].gpioOn = gpioOn
        self.pulses[self.pulse_count].gpioOff = gpioOff
        self.pulses[self.pulse_count].usDelay = usDelay
        self.pulse_count += 1

    # Pull the specified output pin low
    def zero(self, duration):
        self.add_pulse(0, 1 << self.protocol.master.gpio_pin, duration)

    # Protocol-agnostic square wave generator
    def one(self, duration):
        period_time = 1000000.0 / self.protocol.frequency
        on_duration = int(round(period_time * self.protocol.duty_cycle))
        off_duration = int(round(period_time * (1.0 - self.protocol.duty_cycle)))
        total_periods = int(round(duration/period_time))
        total_pulses = total_periods * 2

        # Generate square wave on the specified output pin
        for i in range(total_pulses):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                self.add_pulse(1 << self.protocol.master.gpio_pin, 0, on_duration)
            else:
                self.add_pulse(0, 1 << self.protocol.master.gpio_pin, off_duration)

# NEC protocol class
class NEC():
    def __init__(self,
                master,
                frequency=38000,
                duty_cycle=0.5,
                leading_pulse_duration=9061,
                leading_gap_duration=4473,
                one_pulse_duration = 591,
                one_gap_duration = 1660,
                zero_pulse_duration = 591,
                zero_gap_duration = 521,
                trailing_pulse = [1, 590]):
        self.master = master
        self.wave_generator = Wave_generator(self)
        self.frequency = frequency # in Hz, 38000 per specification
        self.duty_cycle = duty_cycle # duty cycle of high state pulse
        # Durations of high pulse and low "gap".
        # The NEC protocol defines pulse and gap lengths, but we can never expect
        # that any given TV will follow the protocol specification.
        self.leading_pulse_duration = leading_pulse_duration # in microseconds, 9000 per specification
        self.leading_gap_duration = leading_gap_duration # in microseconds, 4500 per specification
        self.one_pulse_duration = one_pulse_duration # in microseconds, 562 per specification
        self.one_gap_duration = one_gap_duration # in microseconds, 1686 per specification
        self.zero_pulse_duration = zero_pulse_duration # in microseconds, 562 per specification
        self.zero_gap_duration = zero_gap_duration # in microseconds, 562 per specification
        self.trailing_pulse = trailing_pulse # trailing 562 microseconds pulse, some remotes send it, some don't
        print("NEC protocol initialized")

    # Send AGC burst before transmission
    def send_agc(self):
        print("Sending AGC burst")
        self.wave_generator.one(self.leading_pulse_duration)
        self.wave_generator.zero(self.leading_gap_duration)

    # Trailing pulse is just a burst with the duration of standard pulse.
    def send_trailing_pulse(self):
        print("Sending trailing pulse")
        self.wave_generator.one(self.trailing_pulse[1])

    # This function is processing IR code. Leaves room for possible manipulation
    # of the code before processing it.
    def process_code(self, ircode):
        if (self.leading_pulse_duration > 0) or (self.leading_gap_duration > 0):
            self.send_agc()
        for i in ircode:
            if i == "0":
                self.zero()
            elif i == "1":
                self.one()
            else:
                print("ERROR! Non-binary digit!")
                return 1
        if self.trailing_pulse[0] == 1:
            self.send_trailing_pulse()
        return 0

    # Generate zero or one in NEC protocol
    # Zero is represented by a pulse and a gap of the same length
    def zero(self):
        self.wave_generator.one(self.zero_pulse_duration)
        self.wave_generator.zero(self.zero_gap_duration)

    # One is represented by a pulse and a gap three times longer than the pulse
    def one(self):
        self.wave_generator.one(self.one_pulse_duration)
        self.wave_generator.zero(self.one_gap_duration)

# RC-5 protocol class
# Note: start bits are not implemented here due to inconsistency between manufacturers.
# Simply provide them with the rest of the IR code.
class RC5():
    def __init__(self,
                master,
                frequency=36000,
                duty_cycle=0.33,
                one_duration=889,
                zero_duration=889):
        self.master = master
        self.wave_generator = Wave_generator(self)
        self.frequency = frequency # in Hz, 36000 per specification
        self.duty_cycle = duty_cycle # duty cycle of high state pulse
        # Durations of high pulse and low "gap".
        # Technically, they both should be the same in the RC-5 protocol, but we can never expect
        # that any given TV will follow the protocol specification.
        self.one_duration = one_duration # in microseconds, 889 per specification
        self.zero_duration = zero_duration # in microseconds, 889 per specification
        print("RC-5 protocol initialized")

    # This function is processing IR code. Leaves room for possible manipulation
    # of the code before processing it.
    def process_code(self, ircode):
        for i in ircode:
            if i == "0":
                self.zero()
            elif i == "1":
                self.one()
            else:
                print("ERROR! Non-binary digit!")
                return 1
        return 0

    # Generate zero or one in RC-5 protocol
    # Zero is represented by pulse-then-low signal
    def zero(self):
        self.wave_generator.one(self.zero_duration)
        self.wave_generator.zero(self.zero_duration)

    # One is represented by low-then-pulse signal
    def one(self):
        self.wave_generator.zero(self.one_duration)
        self.wave_generator.one(self.one_duration)

# RAW IR ones and zeroes. Specify length for one and zero and simply bitbang the GPIO.
# The default values are valid for one tested remote which didn't fit in NEC or RC-5 specifications.
# It can also be used in case you don't want to bother with deciphering raw bytes from IR receiver:
# i.e. instead of trying to figure out the protocol, simply define bit lengths and send them all here.
class RAW():
    def __init__(self,
                master,
                frequency=36000,
                duty_cycle=0.33,
                one_duration=520,
                zero_duration=520):
        self.master = master
        self.wave_generator = Wave_generator(self)
        self.frequency = frequency # in Hz
        self.duty_cycle = duty_cycle # duty cycle of high state pulse
        self.one_duration = one_duration # in microseconds
        self.zero_duration = zero_duration # in microseconds

    def process_code(self, ircode):
        for i in ircode:
            if i == "0":
                self.zero()
            elif i == "1":
                self.one()
            else:
                print("ERROR! Non-binary digit!")
                return 1
        return 0

    # Generate raw zero or one.
    # Zero is represented by low (no signal) for a specified duration.
    def zero(self):
        self.wave_generator.zero(self.zero_duration)

    # One is represented by pulse for a specified duration.
    def one(self):
        self.wave_generator.one(self.one_duration)


class IR():
    def __init__(self, gpio_pin, protocol, protocol_config):
        print("Starting IR")
        print("Loading libpigpio.so")
        self.pigpio = ctypes.CDLL('libpigpio.so')
        print("Initializing pigpio")
        PI_OUTPUT = 1 # from pigpio.h
        self.pigpio.gpioInitialise()
        
        subprocess.Popen('piscope', shell=True)  
        time.sleep(1)
        
        self.gpio_pin = gpio_pin
        print("Configuring pin %d as output" % self.gpio_pin)
        self.pigpio.gpioSetMode(self.gpio_pin, PI_OUTPUT) # pin 17 is used in LIRC by default
        print("Initializing protocol")
        if protocol == "NEC":
            self.protocol = NEC(self, **protocol_config)
        elif protocol == "RC-5":
            self.protocol = RC5(self, **protocol_config)
        elif protocol == "RAW":
            self.protocol = RAW(self, **protocol_config)
        else:
            print("Protocol not specified! Exiting...")
            return 1
        print("IR ready")

    # send_code takes care of sending the processed IR code to pigpio.
    # IR code itself is processed and converted to pigpio structs by protocol's classes.
    def send_code(self, ircode):
        print("Processing IR code: %s" % ircode)
        code = self.protocol.process_code(ircode)
        if code != 0:
            print("Error in processing IR code!")
            return 1
        clear = self.pigpio.gpioWaveClear()
        print(clear)
        if clear != 0:
            print("Error in clearing wave!")
            return 1
        pulses = self.pigpio.gpioWaveAddGeneric(self.protocol.wave_generator.pulse_count, self.protocol.wave_generator.pulses)
        if pulses < 0:
            print("Error in adding wave!")
            return 1
        wave_id = self.pigpio.gpioWaveCreate()
        # Unlike the C implementation, in Python the wave_id seems to always be 0.
        if wave_id >= 0:
            print("Sending wave...")
            result = self.pigpio.gpioWaveTxSend(wave_id, 0)
            if result >= 0:
                print("Success! (result: %d)" % result)
            else:
                print("Error! (result: %d)" % result)
                return 1
        else:
            print("Error creating wave: %d" % wave_id)
            return 1
        while self.pigpio.gpioWaveTxBusy():
            time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Deleting wave")
        self.pigpio.gpioWaveDelete(wave_id)
        print("Terminating pigpio")
        self.pigpio.gpioTerminate()

# Simply define the GPIO pin, protocol (NEC, RC-5 or RAW) and
# override the protocol defaults with the dictionary if required.
# Provide the IR code to the send_code() method.
# An example is given below.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    protocol = "NEC"
    gpio_pin = 23
    protocol_config = dict(one_pulse_duration = 591,
                            zero_pulse_duration = 591)
    ir = IR(gpio_pin, protocol, protocol_config)
    ir.send_code("00100000110111110001000011101111")
    print("Exiting IR")
```

When launching the script it's working, I can see the IR LED blinking through phone cam and also I see the waveform generating through piscope :

[image: piscope IR wave corresponding to the 32 bits code]

Everything looks correct to me but I don't know why it's not powering on my TV...
Could you please help me with this problem ? I don't know if I missed something or if I am using the wrong TV code...

Thanks a lot !

I tried other remote code, I tried the toggle-bit-mask on the first bit (toggle_bit_mask = 0x0)
I tried other codes (on and off) from this page :
https://gist.github.com/francis2110/8f69843dd57ae07dce80
with no success

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working.
I just had to get close to tv (less than 1 meter away).
So I am reviewing my LED setup adding a transistor.
As seen online it should be working from longer distances...

Comment: I have reviewed my IR LED setup and it's indeed working as intended from larger distance by following the new setup (adding transistor between 3.3 V and 5V for more LED power)